# How do I get the same html code from a java request as I do from inspect in Chrome?

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the stream link for a video that is embeded in a website.  Firstly I get the html from the website containg the player.  Then refine this to the embedded link and then from that i get the stream link.  In the past when i have done this I have been able to use Chrome to find the video player element then look for it in Java.  However, when i look for the component i found from chrome it is not in the html code i get from Java.

(this method has worked in the past with different websites)

I'm using Inspect Element in chrome to find the player

This is my code to find an element of a website in Java:

```
//Opens Connection
URL url = new URL(address);

//Gets Data
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36");
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

//Creates bufferd reader
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String inputLine;

//Finds the line
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    if (inputLine.contains(target) == true) {

        break;
    }
}

//Closes The input stream and buffered reader
in.close();
is.close();

//Returns the found line
return inputLine;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Keep in mind that the source code you see in "Inspect Element" is derived from the current DOM.  That's after the AJAX has executed or any JavaScript had executed to replace sections of the page.

Comment: If you select "View page source" instead, you'll see how much of a difference there is between "Inspect Element" and what you will actually see when you download something via Java.

Comment: So your saying that the element i'm looking for is added to the website with JavaScript and is not in the base html code.

Comment: Without knowing the HTML you are looking at, it is a distinct possibility.

Comment: There is almost zero chance that your page has no dynamically generated content. The base code in all likelihood will be different unless you webpage is from the 90's